# How to vote to release a question that has been put on hold?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

At times I find a question posted by a user that is put on hold as unclear to be pretty clear to me. I am able to edit to make the question clearer to the community and so I feel that the question should be released from the hold. So, is there a way to intimate the moderators to release the hold on a question that has been put on hold?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have improved the question to a point where it is understandable, and answerable, you can vote to reopen by clicking the 'reopen' button next to the 'share' and 'edit' buttons under the question. However, you only get that privilege [at 3000 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

But, when you edit a recently closed question, it automatically goes into the reopen queue where people will vote to reopen or not -- you can see whether other people agree with you or not.

But if it's an old question, it won't go back into the queue, in which case, if you think it deserves reopening, comment on it, saying why it should be reopened, and 2 options:

- post a link to the question in Chat and say why it should be reopened: people with  > 3k rep will hopefully see this, and will act accordingly.
- post on *your community's* meta: link to the question, say why it should be reopened. Some meta's have specific tags for questions like these, for example SO has [reopen-closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reopen-closed).

As a ***complete last resort***, flag it for moderator attention, and say 'this should be reopened' and **why**: although it seems mods don't generally accept these flags (quite rightly), because the *community* should have a say, and choose themselves.

Comment: I agree with this but would emphasize that flagging is the tool of last resort.  If the asker has not already commented and/or edited the question and made a good "why" case in the flag I think there is a fair chance that I would decline such a flag on the sites I moderate.

Comment: @PolyGeo edited

Answer (score 2):

When you check [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) you can see there is **cast close and reopen votes**

So if you have 3000 Rep are able to see this option

[image: reopen]

For more you can learn wen you reach 3000 rep